# Bind to child element of content template by name from outside

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

How can I get the binding from the outer `ConnectingLine` (a custom control that binds to `FrameworkElement`s and connects them with a line) to the inner `TextBlock`s named "Top" and "Bottom" to work? Note that I want the whole `FrameworkElement`s for position information.

```
<Grid>
    <ConnectingLine From="{Binding ElementName=Button1.Top}" To="{Binding ElementName=Button2.Top}" />
    <ConnectingLine From="{Binding ElementName=Button1.Bottom}" To="{Binding ElementName=Button2.Bottom}" />
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Button1">
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Top" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Bottom" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="Button2">
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Top" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Bottom" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

My goal is to be able to bind from within XAML. Ideally with no extra fluff, but a solution involving a custom binding operator or attached properties might be acceptable.

Edit: 
How I'd like to have the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Each distinct colored column is one of the templated `ToggleButton`s, already with one dashed `ConnectingLine` between Top and Bottom elements. The horizontal filled lines are what I'm interested in. Currently I'm achieving what I want from code-behind.

Comment: If you override default template you cannot get access to it from XAML. What is the point in binding to TextBlock?

Comment: I want to bind to it so I can draw a line between the two TextBlocks that adapts its start and end points when the TextBlocks move.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it but presumably there is better way out.

Comment: I edited it once more. Thanks for your efforts though.

Comment: You want draw a line, can't you do this between rectangles?

Comment: No, because I have multiple of those ToggleButtons and want to connect their Tops and Bottoms with a line, respectively (Top--Top, Bottom--Bottom). Therefore I have to reach into the guts of each ToggleButton's Template.

Comment: You realize, that From="{Binding ElementName=Button1.Top}" will only bind to control, drawing any kind of lines demands position, don't you?

Comment: `ConnectingLine` is a user control which computes the absolute center positions of its `From` and `To` properties. For that I need the whole FrameworkElement.

Comment: could you post some screen's of your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="Button">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
               <CheckBox x:Name="FindMe" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsChecked}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I should edit my question. I'm actually required to dig the whole control up, so no `Path` in my case, just `{Binding ElementName=...}`. I'm using names, so that I can distinguish between 2 controls of the same type.

Comment: I do not understand, what's wrong with this solution? Explain more precisly what you want to gain.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong, but my question is ill-posed. I'll edit it in a minute.